# When I query MySQL I get a result with \u3000 in it

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, unicode

I'm connecting to a MySQL database, using utf8mbs, with the following code:

```
def name():

    with conn.cursor() as cursor:

        sql = "select name from fake_user where id = 147951"
        cursor.execute(sql)
        interentname = cursor.fetchall()
        for i in interentname:
            i = str(i)
            new_name = i.strip("',)")
            new_name = cc.strip("('")

    # return new_name.encode('utf8').decode('unicode_escape')
    return re.sub("[\u3000]", "", new_name)


print(name())
```

This keeps printing `♚\u3000\u3000 恏`, I want to know how to get rid of the `\u3000` part in that.

The above code doesn't get rid of the `\u3000` though, why is that?

- `interentname` is a tuple
- `new_name` is a `str` string

How do I decode this properly?

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

You are turning each row, a tuple, into a string representation:

```
for i in interentname:
    i = str(i)
```

Don't do that. A tuple is a *sequence* of values, and for your specific query, there will be only a single value in it, the value for the `name` column. Index into the tuple to get the single value:

```
for row in interentname:
    name = row[0]
```

You can also use tuple assignment:

```
for row in interentname:
    name, = row
```

Note the comma after `name` there, it tells Python that `row` must be a sequence with one value and that that one value should be assigned to `name`. You can even do this in the `for` loop target:

```
for name, in interentname:
    print(name)
```

`interentname` is a sequence of tuples, not just a single tuple, so each iteration, you get a value like:

```
>>> row = ('♚\u3000\u3000 恏',)
```

The `\u3000` codepoints in there are U+3000 IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE characters, which Python will always echo as `\uxxxx` escapes when the string is represented (as anything will be inside the standard containers).

By turning a tuple into a string, you then capture the *representation* as a string:

```
>>> str(row)
>>> str(row)
"('♚\\u3000\\u3000 恏',)"
```

Python represents tuples using valid Python syntax, and uses valid Python syntax for strings too. But removing the tuple syntax from that output (so the `"('` at the start and `',)` at the end) does not give you the proper string value back.

Indexing the tuple object gives you the value in it:

```
>>> row[0]
'♚\u3000\u3000 恏'
>>> print(row[0])
♚　　 恏
```

Comment: thank you. But how do I use it?For example, add to a list，I use append method，As usual

Comment: @tom: Just use it. If you have a list, append it to a list, etc. Nothing special about it now.

Comment: For example ,
`l1.append(internetname()[0])`   
`[('♚\u3000\u3000 恏',)]`

Comment: @tom: `internetname()` is a sequence of tuples. `internetname()[0]` is a single tuple. `internetname()[0][0]` would be a single value.

Comment: no `['♚\u3000\u3000 恏']` Back to the origin，It's a problem to take out tuple

Comment: @tom: no, now you have a list with a single string value. Lists also show *representations*, not the string value itself. That's by design, lists and tuples and dictionaries are not meant to be printed for end users, only to help debug a program.